# How do I compile and deliver my application without requiring installation of shared libraries on other machines

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, makefile, g++

On my Ubuntu machine I installed libGLEW. However, I did not install it on my other Ubuntu machine. It works on my compiling machine, but now I received the following error after copying my executable to my other machine.

I want to find a solution where I don't have to require my other machine to install the library. Maybe I can simply share the file along with the executable, like I would do in Windows with DLL files? Would that be possible? And if so, how do I do that?

`error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.2.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

In CMake, I used the following relevant pieces of code:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -g" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m64 -g" )

include_directories(
    ...
    "/usr/include/GL" # Also includes glew.h
)

add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PROJECT_SRC}
)

target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ...
    "GLEW"
)
```

Comment: the simplest option is really to just install the package on the other machine. Otherwise you'd probably have to build it yourself from the sources and statically link it

Comment: There are actually a whole bunch of different ways to do this these days. The most basic being to use static linking, which includes the libraries in your executable. But there are container options and flatpack etc.... There is no single answer.

Comment: Depends on how you want to deploy the lib and on whether the lib you depend on is available via `apt` (or equivalent). Assuming you're building a .deb package for your app, you could simply list the package your app depends on via [`CPACK_DEBIAN[_<COMPONENT>]_PACKAGE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS). Similar functionality exists for other package generators generating a package that is used with package management systems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the issue for my situation, I added `glew.c` to my source files which solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe I can simply share the file along with the executable, like I would do in Windows with DLL files?

It 'depends' on the 'dependencies'.

Use the command [ldd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) to figure out, which libraries are required by a library or program. Those required libraries have to be present (installed) on the target system.

Even if a required library is installed on the target system, it could be possible, that the required version is not available.

That's why the different (linux) systems have their package management systems, which are able to resolve the dependencies and install them automatically.